# Javascript Filter childNodes by CSS Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am using `querySelectorAll` to create a nodeList.

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench)')
```

This array contains ~17 elements and I want to be able to filter these results where the childNode has a certain class.

I am currently using `a[0].childNodes` but this just displays all the children. I only want it to return the specific ones that contain a class `.P-xs`

Comment: `tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench) > .P-xs`?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` or `null`, never an `Array`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but try `querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench).P-xs')`

Comment: The problem is that before I go into the childNodes of my querySelector, I want to save something to a variable. Then I want to go into P-xs

Comment: Is that `P-xs` class in the `tr` or in the `td`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), you should be able to then call `a[0].querySelectorAll('.P-xs')`

Comment: I chose yours because it was the most simple solution

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Function.prototype.call` to borrow `Array.prototype.filter` and be able to use it on your `NodeList`:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench)');
var b = [].filter.call(a, function(el) {
  return el.classList.contains('P-xs');
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer for `childNodes`! But there is one more thing... using `[].filter.call` creates an `Array` instance every time you run that code. The better solution is: `Array.prototype.filter.call`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop on your initial query selector result to create an array only containing those elements with a given descendant. See the example below.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('#one');
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].querySelectorAll('#two').length) {
    b.push(a[i]);
  }
}
b.forEach(function (item, i, array) {
  item.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div id="one">
  One
</div>

<div id="one">
  <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeking for `childNode` contains `P-xs` class then try this. It will return array of all child nodes have that class.

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench)');
var afterFilter = [].concat.apply([], [].map.call(a, function (el) {
    return [].filter.call(el.childNodes, function (ch) {
        return ch.nodeType === 1 && ch.classList.contains('P-xs');
    });
}));
```

But if you want the parent then try below:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.editable:not(.empty-bench)');
var afterFilter = [].map.call(a, function(el) {
    return [].filter.call(el.childNodes, function (ch) {
        return ch.nodeType === 1 && ch.classList.contains('spec');
    });
});
```